# how to align div's horizontally in CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have three child divs inside a container and I want to align these div's horizontally. I tried using the css `float` property but the circles are becoming oval.

Markup Code:

```
 <div class="container info-box clearfix">
   <div class="circle">
     <div class="content">
       <h3>Learn at your own Pace</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Methodic learning</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Unique Approach</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3cb371;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 20%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.circle:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100%; /* 1:1 ratio */
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after{
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after{
  clear: both
}

.info-box{
  margin-top: 20px;
  width:100%;
}

.container{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
  text-align:center;
}

*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

I tried using the float property but the circles are turning into oval. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Code on jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashdeep/v2nD9/2/)

Comment: Do you want to place all 3 circles horizontally instead vertically?

Comment: Yes, I want them to place them horizontally instead of vertically.

Comment: try display:inline-block for circles..

Comment: No it doe not work. I have tried that.

Comment: margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto for each circle

Comment: do you want like this... http://jsfiddle.net/v2nD9/4/ ?

Comment: You may want to consider a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circles are becoming oval because of padding property you have applied. just remove padding: 5px 10px; and add float:left; in the circle class.

```
.circle {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #3cb371;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `display: inline-block;`

http://jsfiddle.net/K6PKK/

Comment: "...the circles are becoming oval"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
div.clearfix {
    display : table;
}

div.circle {
    display : table-cell;
}
```